# What is 3Dnew in Vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

First of, I have no idea about VBscript or any of microsoft technologies. I came across this in one of the websites I was using and curios as to what it meant.

```
var locator=3Dnew ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
var service =3D locator.ConnectServer(".");
var properties=3Dservice.ExecQuery("select * from =
win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
```

There are a lot of 3D in the script. Can anyone explain what this means? I am not 100% sure if this is VBscript. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not VBScript. It's a problem with the encoding of the file. The sequence =3D is the US-ASCII code for the equal sign in [Quoted-Printable encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).